# can we normalize text data in machine learning using python

Tags: machine-learning, python, svm, scikit-learn

i have developed a application for text classification ,it is taking to much time to execute support vector machine due to normalization issue,so that i am asking ,can we normalize the  text data using python ,
please suggest the examples  for this  issue.

below my sample code :pipe = Pipeline([("cleaner", predictors()),
                 ('tfidf_vector', tfidf_vector),
                 ('classifier', classifier)])

pipe.fit(X_train,y_train_)

Comment: how did you form up your numerical features to be fed into SVM?

Comment: i am using tf-idf to convert text to numeric .